# Ektron C# Page - Where to debug when error occurs before Page_Init()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ektron

I've an Ektron C# web forms application that I'm setting up for multilingual capability.  So far, all Ektron settings seem good (as per documentation) for displaying pages in French.  However, when I select the language by passing ?langtype=1036 (French locale ID) on the querystring, an Error 500 is raised (BTW, I've enabled detailed error message reporting in web.config as well as IIS and I still get that 500).

After much Googling, I haven't found any indication of why the problem occurs.  So, I'm thinking, easy enough to debug, right?  I've placed in the following code at every relevant application or page event handler I can think of.  Example:

global.asax:

```
void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Context.Response.Write("Application_EndRequest");
}
```

From a page or masterpage:

```
void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Context.Response.Write("Page_Init");
}
```

Within these events I would page in and take out...

```
Response.End();
```

...to see what events were actually triggering prior to the exception (hoping I could debug within one of them).  The 500 error is raised after the Application_EndRequest event and before Page_Init or Page_PreInit.

So, I'm wondering:
 + Are there events I'm overlooking for which I can debug the error?
 + Is there another tactic I can take for debugging this rather than using events?
 + Is this something probably happening within an Ektron DLL that I've no ability to debug?

Any help would be most appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: In web.config, you can set LogLevel=3 or 4 to get detailed logging out of Ektron's code. What are the details of the error? Have you looked in the application log to see what's going on?

Comment: You would need to paste in the actual error message and stack trace to see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

At times like this, the Application Event Log is your friend.  Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Computer Management.  Then in the left pane, expand System Tools, then Event Viewer, then Windows Logs, then click on Application.

You might need, as egandalf noted, to change the LogLevel in order to get enough data to diagnose the problem.  Here's the relevant portion of web.config to look for when making this change.

```xml
<system.diagnostics>
    <switches>
        <!-- Determines the level of messages that are logged
        1 = Error:  Only Errors are logged.
        2 = Warning:  Only warnings and Errors are logged.
        3 = Information:  Only Informationals, Warnings, and Errors are logged.
        4 = Verbose:  Everything is logged.

        NOTE: you can configure where each message level is logged using the instrumentation.config.
        -->
        <add name="LogLevel" value="1" />
    </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

The other thing that helps me when I'm debugging issues like this is to remove anything "extra".  Try a new CMS Min site pointing to your existing database.  Does the same thing happen with that site?  If that doesn't get you anywhere, try removing the Modules from web.config and then adding them back in, one at a time.  Perhaps you can use the process of elimination to determine if the error is occurring in any of the modules.

**UPDATE:**

I know you stated in your question that "so far, all Ektron settings seem good...".  However, I do think it's important to note that languages must be enabled via the workarea (Settings > Localization > Languages and Regions), and that it is possible for languages to be enabled in the workarea and not on the site.  On this page of the workarea, a check means it's enabled on the site, a triangle means it's enabled in the workarea only and not on the site.  It might be worth double-checking this page in your workarea.